# Unable to run network manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

i have a w541 thinkpad running ubuntu 20.04.6
I work for an isp so i am often in "Advanced Network Configuration" to edit vlan interfaces on my machine, which i have been doing success fully for a year now.

A lot of the time, i need to reboot my computer for these vlan changes to take effect. So after changing an ip address to DHCP, i rebooted my machine for the changes to take effect.

Following a reboot, the gnome desktop doesnt seem to like the network anymore, saying that network manager needs to be running.

I removed and purged the network-manager rebooted, etc and it still won't run.

```
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendo>
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2023-07-17 16:32:13 MDT; 32mi>
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 7383 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=dumped, >
   Main PID: 7383 (code=dumped, signal=SEGV)
lines 1-6/6 (END)
```

any ideas on what i can do? I can manually tell the interface to be a dhcp client, but doesnt really work for the nature of my job.

outputof the command you told me
thanks much
ul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6696] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (after a restart)
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6696] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6714] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6735] manager[0x55a2a5c74040]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6735] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6746] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6746] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "lacomputadoradecfiddy"
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6748] dns-mgr[0x55a2a5c5f290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6755] rfkill2: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6757] manager[0x55a2a5c74040]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6757] manager[0x55a2a5c74040]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6768] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6776] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6781] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6785] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6787] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6791] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6792] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6794] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6795] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6797] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkM>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6798] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6798] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6798] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6798] ifupdown:       interface-parser: source line includes interfaces file(s) /etc/>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.6799] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.8376] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.8379] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.8394] manager: (enp0s25): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Device>
Jul 17 20:57:58 lacomputadoradecfiddy NetworkManager[1341]:   [1689649078.8403] device (enp0s25): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys>
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Jul 17 20:57:59 lacomputadoradecfiddy systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Answer (score 0):

when i uninstalled network manager, it didnt remove the networkmanager directory in /etc directory. not wanting to lose anything important, i renamed this "poopNetworkManager" and then uninstalled and reinstalled networkmanager one last time and i got it working.

Yay me for fixing it myself